# Meta tags for URL with description and image (In Skype, Discord)

Tags: html, discord, meta, skype

When someone sends a link in Skype or Discord, it can show an image and description, for example:
[image: Skype (Img + Descr)]
[image: Discord (Img + Descr)]

I think it's because of `<meta>` tags in the HTML `<head>` element.
But HTML supports hundreds of `<meta>` tags... I found this page on GitHub, Link: https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/1978404
And that's so many tags. Is there someone who knows which tags are used to provide these images and descriptions on Skype and Discord?

I tried adding some meta tags, favicon, and title, but it doesn't work and I don't know which `<meta>` tags I need.

Code I tried:

```html
<title>Weird Website</title>
<meta name="description" content="Ehm.. weird website"/>
<meta name="url" content="http://www.weirdwebsite.idk/">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

And it looks like this...

Skype is taking the `<title>` contents but missing the image:
[image: Skype (Title of page)]

Discord only shows a basic link:
[image: Discord (Only URL)]

Does anyone know how to automatically add image and some text when a link is shared in these apps?
*(btw zzz.com isn't my website, only for example)*

Thanks,
Oliver.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Site Title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://my.site.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://my.site.com/images/thumb.png" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Site description" />
<meta name="theme-color" content="#FF0000">

<!-- Include this to make the og:image larger -->
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
```

And the image displayed as the link preview on Skype is the thumb image specified in og:image (that is not available anywhere else on the page).

Keep in mind that Skype may also cache information.

Comment: The same thing happens to me currently with a couple of new domains.
Perhaps it is as you say a problem with the Skype cache, but in the PC version I cannot find a way to clean Skype cache, from what I have read for Windows 10 app, you have to clean the Windows cache, browsers, etc.
Anyway I already did that and the image is not seen on Skype, if it looks good on Facebook and Twitter.

Comment: You can use https://metatags.io for generating meta tags for your site, Its really useful

Comment: With the above tags, my favicon only shows along with links of the main site, i.e it shows the image on https://example.com and not on https://example.com/abc. Any clue why that may be happening?