# How to get a description of your website when sharing it in social media for example discord

Tags: html, discord, social-media

When I share my portfolio I want to have it give a short description, like it does with most major websites. I don't know how to get a small box of information under it. I'll post images that have one with a description and one without

Comment: Bad one http://prntscr.com/psw4xi

Comment: Good one http://prntscr.com/psw59m

Answer (score 3):

You need to add meta tags to your HTML.

[For facebook, you can use this to test](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) (in general this tends to be a good testing tool for most platforms)

[For discord links, check out this answer for more info and a template of meta tags to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54266598/meta-tags-for-url-with-description-and-image-in-skype-discord)

[You can see this link for a full list of meta tags](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/1978404)