# Screenshot Link thingy

Tags: discord, screenshot

Sorry for the bad explanation.

On Discord there are people that have a cool custom link along with an embed screenshot and some text.
I'd like to ask how to do this

Example: [Click for the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPtQ8.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's because the link they sent (alayn.should-not-exist.xyz) has a meta description tag so Discord can generate a preview. Here is a post with more information: [Meta tags for URL with description and image (In Skype, Discord)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54266598/meta-tags-for-url-with-description-and-image-in-skype-discord).